# How to limit the number of requests per minute in a .net core api

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .Net Core API that has a single end point, I only need to allow five requests per minute on that endpoint. Does anyone know how I can make this request control?

Comment: Please define what you want as limit. Limit on the side of the API or of the side of an app you write that calls up?

Comment: I need a limit on the side of the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should review the AspNetCoreRateLimit NuGet package that can handle a wide variety of rate limiting scenarios.  It's not clear from your post if you want to limit this to an absolute five requests per minute total for all users, or if you are using an API key or some other client ID.  This middleware has built in options for limiting by IP Address or a custom defined client ID.

https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit

You can also view a short tutorial on the use of this middleware here:
https://blog.elmah.io/rate-limiting-api-requests-with-asp-net-core-and-aspnetcoreratelimit/